# Pandas: find common values across columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TX':['bob','tim','frank'],'IL':['fred','bob','tim'],'NE':['tim','joe','bob']})
```

I would like to isolate the strings that occur across all columns to generate a list. The expected result is:

```
output = ['tim','bob']
```

The only way I can think to achieve this is using for loops which I would like to avoid. Is there a built-in pandas function suited to accomplishing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create mask for count values per columns and test if not missing values per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
m = df.apply(pd.value_counts).notna()
print (m)
          TX     IL     NE
bob     True   True   True
frank   True  False  False
fred   False   True  False
joe    False  False   True
tim     True   True   True

L = m.index[m.all(axis=1)].tolist()
print (L)
['bob', 'tim']
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

you can stack all your columns vertically and then do a `value_counts` to count the occurrences of each item, we'll do that in the variable called `s`

we then want all occurrences of the names which are equal to the `max` number of occurrences, in this instance 3, the column values are now indices thanks to using `stack`

```
s = df.stack().value_counts()
# or if you want to ignore duplicates column wise
#df.stack().groupby(level=1).unique().explode().value_counts()

print(s)

tim      3
bob      3
frank    1
fred     1
joe      1

s1 = s[s.eq(s.max())].index.tolist()

print(s1)

['tim', 'bob']
```

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: This might fail if the same value appears in one column more than once. For example say, `bob` appeared twice in the first column, `df.stack.value_counts()` would give `4 for 'bob'` and thus `s1` would only return `['bob']` which is wrong according to the question.

Comment: correct @nishant but in the absence of any feedback from OP it's hard to say what's wrong or right, the above could be corrected by `df.stack().groupby(level=1).unique().explode().value_counts()`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by [`pandas.DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`set.intersection()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/intersection), like this:

```
cols_set = list(df.apply(lambda col: set(col.values)).values)
output = list(set.intersection(*cols_set))
```

The result is following:

```
>>> print(output)
['tim', 'bob']
```

Comment: `list(set.intersection(*[set(col) for col in df.values]))`. Summary of the above answer. Achieves the same result in lesser amount of code.

Comment: @nishant, thank you for your comment. However, you are *not* right. The code could be used for a problem from the question only if it looked like this: `list(set.intersection(*[set(col) for col in df.values.T]))`. The author of the question is interested in values common for every column, not row! Next time, please, read the question carefully.

Comment: @Jaroslav..yes you are correct. I missed `df.T` i.e. transpose of the data frame. Actual code would be `list(set.intersection(*[set(col) for col in df.T.values]))`